# Copy multiple column names into variables in each row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as :-

```
Country    Disease 1   Disease 2    Disease 3   Disease4 

A           No         No          No          Yes     
B           Yes        Yes         No          No     
C           No         Yes         No          No   
D           No         No          Yes         No
```

I want to make as :-

```
Country     Disease
A           Disease4
B           Disease1
B           Disease2
C           Disease2
D           Disease3
```

I am unable to do it with:

```
New_Data_3 <- melt(New_Data2, id = c("Country"))
```

`New_Data_2` is the dataframe.

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `rstudio` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add two more steps to get your desired output after using `melt`. The code is:

```
require(dplyr)
require(reshape2)

New_Data_3 = melt(New_Data_2,id=c('Country')) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(value=='Yes') %>% 
  dplyr::rename(Disease = variable) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-value)
```

Let me know if that works for you.